# Block until async function finishes

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, decorator, blocking

**What I need:**

```
asyncFunc(..., function cb() {
  console.log("async function finished");
});
console.log("AFTER async function finished");
```

I am aware that the title and this example may trigger some strong responses regarding proper async programming in JS, but if you don't believe me that this is at least an ok solution, I added a description why I need it this way, but I would also be quite happy with something "better".

My project uses the newest version of typescript, therefore a possible solution could use async/await, generators or anything else from the newer concepts.

**Why I need it:**

I know that this is wrong in most contexts and I may have overlooked some options in the specifics, but I think that's the best solution.

I am developing a library that runs before the actual project (Angular, React, ...) and is based on [@Decorators](https://medium.com/google-developers/exploring-es7-decorators-76ecb65fb841). This library is only used in development, therefore the added startup time - which is introduced by a blocking solution - is acceptable. I have a class decorator that sets up a data structure which then is used inside other decorators. The data structure setup is asynchronous (asyncFunc from above) and I need to halt further execution until the data structure is set up, otherwise it is not ready when the decorators that use this data are called. Since decorators are decoupled and have a predefined signature and behavior, I am not aware of any way to make them asynchronous or dependent on another function.

thanks

Comment: _"I need to halt further execution "_ Can you really not trigger that further execution from a callback/promise resolution?  Anything other than that is just fighting against things

Comment: You need a `sync` call instead of `async` there might be any way to make that call sync. For instance, in `jQuery` ajax calls you can add `async: false` to the options

Comment: @James Thrope I tried some other solutions and already "fought" some battles and came to the conclusion that this may be the best solution. Class decorators are evaluated last, therefore if I call the async function and then immediately return the decorator function the underlying project gets executed. From this point on every (decorator) function that is dependent on the data structure can and will be called.

Comment: @josec89 That's probably not too relevant here, but it's worth noting [that doing so is deprecated and discouraged](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#sync-warning)

Comment: @josec89 Exactly that's what I need, the problem is that the function that initiates the data structure is provided by a library and is asynchronous. Essentially my question is how do I manually transform an async into a sync function.

Comment: @KenavR You probably can't :| but maybe you could `require` the `startpoint` (or whatever) of your framework once you are in the callback. But sounds like a difficult task to achieve :D good luck ˆ^

Comment: @JamesThorpe The fact that `sync` calls are deprecated or best not to be used is obvious and worth nothing here, the author knows that and is still wondering how to make it happen :D

Comment: @KenavR: "*runs before the actual project*" - does the project have a simple entry point? You could delay *that* until after all your decorators have done their asynchronous job. But no, there's no solution that can block until something asynchronous is done, you always will need to wrap the "AFTER async finished" code.